# How to get list of data with where condition in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to get REST url to retrieve data where name="hello" and category="main"

This is my Model

```
public function show($name, $category)
    {
        $FodMap = FodMap::find($name, $category);
        return $FodMap;


    }
```

Routes

```
Route::get('FodMap/{name}/{category}', 'FodMapController@show');
```

What I want is when I type `localhost/api/FodMap/hello/main`

All result should display which matches with hello and main

Please advise me to proceed.... I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: The process starts with reading the [Laravel manual](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) coding something and then if you cannot get it quite as you want it, ask again here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The eloquent query is something like this:

```
FodMap::where('name','=',$name)->where('category','=',$category)->get()
```

That will return an Eloquent Collection instance.

Comment: Thanks... appreciate the guide

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getAllData()
{
    $data = tableName::where('Method','Delivery')->get();
    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```

OR

```
$users = DB::table_Name('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get();
```

OR

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                    ->get();
```